# Wordpress get links from field textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

i make textarea field in wordpress

```
$xbox->add_field(
        array(
            'id'   => 'examplelink',
            'name' => esc_html__( 'examplelink', 'wpst' ),
            'type' => 'textarea',
            'desc' => esc_html__( 'test', 'wpst' ),
        )
    );
```

In textarea i put random multi link example :

`https://www.google.com/random-text`

`https://www.yahoo.com/random-text`

`https://www.example.com//random-text`

how i can call in outside post to get each link alone

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/random-text" target="_blank">google.com</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/random-text" target="_blank">yahoo.com</a>
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com/random-text" target="_blank">yahoo.com</a>
```

EDIT:
i tried this solution and is worked

```
<?php $lines = explode("\n", $examplelink);
if ( !empty($lines) ) {
  
  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    echo '<a class="my-button" href="'. trim( $line ) .'" target="_blank">Link Name</a>' ; 
  }

}
?>
```

how i can get every href name with this

```
<?= parse_url(($examplelink), PHP_URL_HOST); ?>
```

Comment: ACF would make your life a hundred times easier. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: ACF THE SAME textarea field MY PROBLEM IS TO SPLIT EVERY LINK ALONE

Comment: It would be easier to just add multiple fields. But if you really wanted to do it this way, I imagine it would be a combination of `strpos` and `substr`

Comment: i found this wich make every lgne from the textarea alone

<?php $lines = explode("\n", $examplelink); 
if ( !empty($lines) ) {
  
  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    echo '<a class="my-button" href="'. trim( $line ) .'" target="_blank">link name</a>' ; 
  }
  
  
 
}

is there is any way to add <?= parse_url(($examplelink), PHP_URL_HOST); ?>
to get every link name from the link

Comment: You should probably look up some kind of REGEX. That will probably be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I GOT IT!
this will get each link with name of the domain
The final code:

```
<?php $lines = explode("\n", $examplelink); 
if ( !empty($lines) ) {
  
  foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    echo '<a href="'. trim( $line ) .'" target="_blank">'. parse_url(($line), PHP_URL_HOST) .'</a>' ; 
}}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below.

```
<?php
function linkExtractor($html)
{
 $linkArray = array();
 if(preg_match_all('/<a\s+.*?href=[\"\']?([^\"\' >]*)[\"\']?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/i', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)){
  foreach ($matches as $match) {
   array_push($linkArray, array($match[1], $match[2]));
  }
 }
 return $linkArray;
}
$links = linkExtractor($examplelink);
// Your code...
?>
```